# Javascript Block Form action on "enter" submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm working in laravel framework, and i have this form:

**VIEW**

```
{!! Form::open() !!} 
<input type="text" name="puntata" id="puntata"> 
<button id="registro" type="button" class="btn-primary">PUNTA</button>
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

**JS**

```
var button = d.getElementById('registro');
   function puntata() {
      ....my code...
   }
var submit = button.onclick = puntata;
```

When i insert a value in my input "puntata" and do click on button "registro" it call my function js, it work well.

But If i insert a value in my input "puntata" and i do "ENTER" in my keyboard it submit the form without call my function javascript. How can i block this?

i would like that on event "ENTER" call my function puntata() and NOT submit the form.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You add the event handler to the the form submit instead, and use a submit button

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery's [`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).keydown(function(event){

    if(event.keyCode == 13) { // -- 13 for enter key
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#registro').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the event handler to the form submission and not the button being clicked.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // whatever you were doing on button click
});
```